# Data Recovery software for Mac hard drive that does not display on desktop

Tags: mac, data-recovery

Is there a data recovery recovery software that works for hard drives that do not display on the desktop?

This is a laptop.  It is booting from an external drive.  The internal drive does not display on the desktop.  It is also not listed as an installable partition during MAC OS X installation.  Is there anything that can recover a *volume* in this condition?  I commonly see file recovery,but what I need is the partition to recover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) would recover a drive if need be - you should be able to install and run this off your current external install, assuming its OS X or linux

Answer (score 0):

I recently had good luck in this scenario by removing the internal hard drive and mounting it to a Windows desktop then using the Apple Bootcamp HFS drivers to view the partition and recover the data :) Sounds like a workaround but I tried dozens of solutions before giving this a chance with success!

Comment: please do not use answers to post a "thanks" comment... thats what comments are for ;)

Comment: I dont think this is a thanks comment - it is a tip? I solved that same issue by using the bootcamp drivers...